# Why will my program not flag characters?

Tags: c

I'm making this program using switch statements that will assign letter grades based on if the user enters numbers 0 - 10. If the user enters a number that is not 0-10, the program outputs an error message and has the user re-enter. However, if the user enters a character the program will loop at the default case. I want it to output the error message from the default case once, and have them re-enter if they enter a character. I'm not sure as to why it loops the default case when a character is entered though.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int grade;
    int r;
    while((r = scanf("%i", &grade)) != EOF)
    {
        switch(grade)
            {
                case 10:
                case 9:
                    printf("Your grade is an A\n");
                    break;
                case 8:
                    printf("Your grade is a B\n");
                    break;
                case 7:
                    printf("Your grade is a C\n");
                    break;
                case 6:
                    printf("Your grade is a D\n");
                    break;
                case 5:
                case 4:
                case 3:
                case 2:
                case 1:
                case 0:
                    printf("Your grade is an F\n");
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("Invalid score, please re-enter\n");
            }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: What does `scanf` return if you type something invalid? (You can find this out by reading the documentation)

Comment: You're saving the return value of `scanf` into `r` (that's good), but then you're only checking it against `EOF`. If the user enters something that can't be converted into a number, `r` will be zero, otherwise one.

Comment: The test should be `== 1` rather than `!= EOF`

Comment: You should probably use `%d` rather than `%i`  .  The `%i` will translate `010` into `8` for example.

Comment: @M.M: My bad, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int grade;
    int r=0;
    while(r != 1)
    {
    scanf("%i", &grade);
        switch(grade)
            {
                case 10:
                case 9:
                    printf("Your grade is an A\n");
                    r=1
                    break;
                case 8:
                    printf("Your grade is a B\n");
                    r=1
                    break;
                case 7:
                    printf("Your grade is a C\n");
                    r=1
                    break;
                case 6:
                    printf("Your grade is a D\n");
                    r=1
                    break;
                case 5:
                case 4:
                case 3:
                case 2:
                case 1:
                case 0:
                    printf("Your grade is an F\n");
                    r=1
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("Invalid score, please re-enter\n");
                    break;
            }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: but my while breaks whenever r =1 so itll be an infinite loop until the user enters a valid score

Answer (score 1):

This will clear the input buffer on an invalid input and allow a retry.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int grade;
    int r;
    while((r = scanf("%i", &grade)) != EOF)
    {
        if ( r != 1) {//r == 1 is successful input of integer
            grade = -1;//reset grade on invalid input
        }
        switch(grade)
        {
            case 10:
            case 9:
                printf("Your grade is an A\n");
                break;
            case 8:
                printf("Your grade is a B\n");
                break;
            case 7:
                printf("Your grade is a C\n");
                break;
            case 6:
                printf("Your grade is a D\n");
                break;
            case 5:
            case 4:
            case 3:
            case 2:
            case 1:
            case 0:
                printf("Your grade is an F\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Invalid score, please re-enter\n");
                while ( getchar() != '\n');//clear input buffer
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code always loops is because there is no way to exit out of your `while` other than to kill the program. Remember that `break` only breaks out of the inner-most `switch` or loop.

The cleanest way to break out of multiple levels is to use a flag. One way to do what you want is like this:

```
bool valid_grade = false;
while(!valid_grade && (r = scanf("%i", &grade)) != EOF)
{
    valid_grade = true;
    switch(grade)
        {
            case 10:

             // unchanged from your code

            default:
                valid_grade = false;
                printf("Invalid score, please re-enter\n");
        }
}
```

Comment: This works, but it will quit the program once it detects the incorrect data. I'm mainly confused on how I would get it to properly flush the data, and continue to ask the user for input until EOF

Comment: @retrohelix94 that will keep asking if there is an invalid input then quit once it gets a correct input. Isn't that what you want?